# Prevent same files/photos select

Tags: filepond

Is there any way to prevent adding already selected files? For instance, detect if same name already exist in previously added files? Any checks before form posting or sending to the server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the solution I've used with a Filepond instance called "pond":

```
var filenames = [];
pond.on('addfile',
    function(error, file){
        if(filenames.includes(file.filename)){
            error = {
                main: 'duplicate',
                sub: 'A file with that name already exists in the pond.'
            }
            handleFileError(error, file);
        }
        if(error) handleFileError(error, file);
        filenames.push(file.filename);
    });

pond.on('removefile',
    function(error, file){
        var index = filenames.indexOf(file.filename);
        filenames.splice(index, 1);
    });

function handleFileError(error, file){
    var err = document.querySelector(".filepond-error");
    err.innerHTML = file.filename + " cannot be loaded " + error.sub;
    pond.removeFile(file);
}
```

Comment: For the first time it is working, and if you upload it again it is accepting

Comment: @Developer That's how it's supposed to work on the client side. Unless you let the client know which files have already been uploaded, there's no way for Filepond to know which files already exist on the server. If you want to ignore a file that shares the same name as a file you've already uploaded, that code needs to be on the server you're posting to.

Comment: Do we have a method to handle removefile?

Comment: I came up with this approach https://jsfiddle.net/DorababuMeka/ydj2aruL/

Comment: The problem with that approach is that all of the information about what files have been uploaded is lost as soon as the user navigates away from or refreshes the page. If you really want to prevent any duplicate files from being uploaded, that's better suited for the back end where you have better access to the files, can run more comprehensive checks (e.g. check if their hashed value is the same meaning identical files), and quietly ignore any duplicates.