# File pond prevent duplicate file upload

Tags: jquery, filepond

Hello I am using filepond for uploading files from here https://pqina.nl/filepond/docs/getting-started/examples/

I have explored the documentation and from the answer here I tried few

[Prevent same files/photos select](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59736525/prevent-same-files-photos-select)

```
 var pond;
 pond = FilePond.create(
        document.querySelector('input.filepond')
    );
```

I tried triggering the removefile and see if I am getting any files to it as follows

```
pond.on('removefile', function (file) {
        alert(file);
    });
```

But this return null, I tried this logic in

```
pond.on('addfile',
        function (error, file) {
        var fileCnt = pond.getFiles();
 });
```

This gives me the count but I am trying to handle something like before file upload event if anything is there. Or is there any alternate file control which behaves the same please suggest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK I came up with this approach in addition to this answer here

[Prevent same files/photos select](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59736525/prevent-same-files-photos-select)

```
var pond;
var filenames = [];
pond = FilePond.create(
 document.querySelector('input.filepond')
);

pond.on('removefile', function (err, f) {
   filenames = [];
   var fileCnt = pond.getFiles().length;
   for (var fCnt = 0; fCnt < fileCnt; fCnt++) {
      var file = pond.getFile(fCnt);
      filenames.push(file.filename);
    }
 });

pond.on('addfile',
  function (error, file) {
    if (filenames.includes(file.filename)) {
        var fileError = "A file with name " + file.filename + " was already uploaded";
        alert(fileError);
        handleFileError(file);
      }
      if (error) handleFileError(error, file);
       filenames.push(file.filename);
    });
    function handleFileError(file) {
        pond.removeFile(file);
    }
```

Fiddle for the same https://jsfiddle.net/DorababuMeka/ydj2aruL/